# Closed form from a slightly modified recursion for transposed Catalan triangle

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

- Let $a_1(n)$ be [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108), i.e. Catalan numbers. Here
  $$
  a_1(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
  $$
- Let $a_2(n)$ be [A059715](https://oeis.org/A059715), i.e. number of multi-directed animals on the triangular lattice. From OEIS page we know that the generating function is known in closed form. It is big and non-D-finite.
- Let
  $$
  L_1(n, j)=\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-j-1}\binom{j+p+1}{p+1}L_1(n-j-1, p), \\
  L_1(n,n)=1
  $$
  Here it looks like that $L_1(n,j)$ is [A033184](https://oeis.org/A033184), i.e. transposed Catalan triangle.
- Let
  $$
  L_2(n, j)=\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-j-1}\binom{j+p+2}{p+1}L_2(n-j-1, p), \\
  L_2(n,n)=1
  $$

I conjecture that
$$
a_1(n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}L_1(n-1,j), \\
a_2(n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}L_2(n-1,j)
$$
Is there a way to prove it? Is there a way to get closed form for $a_2(n)$ from the recursion for $L_2(n,j)$?